# How to send button control between the ViewModels?

Tags: mvvm

I know that view controls should not be present in ViewModel, but in one specific situation I have to send a button object from one assembly to another. Is it ok to make at least a property of type 'object' like below in ViewModel?

```
public object StoreButtonControl {get;set;} // for storing the button
```

Or does it break the MVVM?

Comment: could you specify why you need the Button in the VM, maybe there is a better solution

Comment: becaue in another view, I want to do DoubleAnimation on this button: <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Studio" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.3" To="0" Duration="0:0:2"/>